# ECS migration from AL1 to AL2 - ECS service not starting

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I have recently changed AMI on which my ECS EC2 instances are running from Amazon Linux to Amazon Linux 2 (in both cases I am using ECS optimized images). I am deploying my instances using cloudformation and having a real headache as those new instances sometimes are being run successfully and sometimes not (same stack, no updates, same code).
On the failed instances I see that there is an issue with ECS service itself after executing ecs-logs-collector.sh I see in ecs file log "warning: The Amazon ECS Container Agent is not running". Also directory "/var/log/ecs" doesn't even exist!.

I have correct IAM role attached to an instance.

Also as mentioned, it is the same code being run, and on 75% of attempts it fails with ECS service, I have no more ideas, where else to look for some issues/logs/errors.

AMI: ami-0650e7d86452db33b (eu-central-1)

Answer (score 1):

Solved. If someone will fall into this issue adding this to my userdata helped:

```
cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/ecs.service /etc/systemd/system/ecs.service
sed -i '/After=cloud-final.service/d' /etc/systemd/system/ecs.service
systemctl daemon-reload
```